# Apache2 mod_substitute not modifying URLs

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2

I'm trying to use Apache2 as a reverse proxy to access an application (calibre web) running inside a Docker container. Since the application is using redirects (more details [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1126932/apache2-rewrite-http-redirects)), I'm trying to use apache's [mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html) to modify the URLs in the redirects so they point to the right URL. I wrote the following inside a file called `calibreweb.conf` and enabled both the site and the `substitute` mod.

```
<Location /calibre-web>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8083
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8083
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s|https://subdomain.example.com/|https://subdomain.example.com/calibre-web/|i"

</Location>
```

The problem is that, after restarting Apache, the mod isn't doing anything. As a sanity check I tried changing the substitute pattern to `Substitute "s|admin|user|i"`, as the first redirect contains `admin`, but I still get redirected to `subdomain.example.com/admin/dbconfig`.
Adding `SetOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE,DEFLATE` just above the `AddOutputFilterByType` line didn't help.
Also removing the content-type filter so that the file becomes

```
<Location /calibre-web>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8083
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8083
    Substitute "s|https://nas.gtpware.eu/|https://nas.gtpware.eu/calibre-web/|i"

</Location>
```

didn't fix it.
Any idea why this doesn't work? It looks like the example given in Apache2's documentation to me.
Thank you for your help,

GTP95

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Calibre web has a working example in their wiki [here](https://github.com/janeczku/calibre-web/wiki/Setup-Reverse-Proxy). It boils down to:

```
<Location /calibre-web >
        RequestHeader set X-SCRIPT-NAME /calibre-web
        RequestHeader set X-SCHEME https
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8083/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8083/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  /  /calibre-web/
</Location>
```